# JavaFX Application crashs when on many WebView Open

Tags: java, webview, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

In my app, I'm using webviews inside tab. When i open some more tab then JVM crashes. What can be the reason?

**error log:**

```
  #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000101e50260, pid=6404, tid=5704
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0-b132) (build 1.8.0-b132)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b70 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  0x0000000101e50260
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #
```

Error details in pastebin http://paste.ubuntu.com/9650264/

Comment: do you have logging enabled to a level finer than INFO? I had WebView crashes when com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.level is set finer than INFO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that jdk version was b13. Thats older. I changed to new one. It works like a charm now.

Comment: you might accept your answer so that the question is not listed as unanswered anymore